# Allow front-end translation editing in Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

In my Laravel application I would like to allow my (super) users to define language translations from the front-end. AFAIK there is no `Lang::all()` or something like this that provides the list of language variables. I am looking for a way to parse language keys for a language and allow the values to be defined by the end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you are correct, there isn't any Lang:all()-ish function returning all the registered lang keys.

If you want to have such ability to list all the registered variables, config may be the way to go - there you are able to fetch a complete list of keys. In my opinion though, that's somewhat a messy solution to substitute lang with config. Even more messy, you could leverage the line replacement mechanism in lang

```
 echo Lang::get('messages.welcome', array('name' => 'Shakur'));
```

but ofcourse you'd need to write the rest of you idea around it.

Instead I guess it's best to DRY your way out of the issue (Dont Repeat Yourself) :) A quick reckon reveals a solution to your problem is already available:

the [waavi/translation](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/waavi/translation) package should fit your needs, it's a "translation package for Laravel 4 with database and cache support"

From the docs:

> Upgrading Laravel's localization module Keeping a project's
>   translations properly updated is cumbersome. Usually translators do
>   not have access to the codebase, and even when they do it's hard to
>   keep track of which translations are missing for each language or when
>   updates to the original text require that translations be revised.
>
> This package allows developers to leverage their database and cache to
>   manage multilanguage sites, while still working on language files
>   during development and benefiting from all the features Laravel's
>   Translation bundle has, like pluralization or replacement.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I prefer to keep my laravel installation clean of modules. I will accept the answer though in case someone else finds this module useful. I hope Laravel guys will add a way for accessing translation array and setting language variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    $loader = app('translator')->getLoader();
    $locale = Config::get('app.locale');
    $lines = $loader->load($locale, 'messages', '*');
    foreach ($lines as $key=>$value){
            print($key . ":" . $value);
    }
```

Comment: that is exactly I was looking. Thanks gijs. you are genius